# Data on site not showing after clicking on sub menu on nested unordered list using ajax with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, java-ee-7

Here is the html unordered list implementation

```
<div id="dropdownmenu" style="position: fixed; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; position: fixed; opacity: 1; text-align: center;">
        <ul id='navbar' class="menu">
            <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#s2"><%= session.getAttribute("name") %></a>
            <ul id='profile' class="submenu">
            <li id='account'>Account</li>
            <li id='password'><a>Change Password</a></li>
            <li id='myitinerary'><a>My Itineraries</a></li>
            <li id='promotions'><a>Promotions</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/ExpressBus-war/Logout">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

and here is the script i am trying to run

```
<script>         
            $(function() {
                $("#dropdownmenu").click(function(event) {
                    if(event.target.id === 'myitinerary')
                    {
                        $.post({
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {
                                username: <%= session.getAttribute("username") %>;
                            },
                            url: "GetItineraries",
                            success: function(result){
                                $('#content2').empty();
                                $("#content3").empty();
                                $("#content4").empty();
                                $('#content').html(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I am using Netbeans EE, basically what i intend to do is to fill the content with the result i obtained from the servlet. But so far everything i have tried isnt working out.

Comment: Any errors in the console? If so, what are they?

Comment: The only error i got was an unexpected token error in chrome. Other than that nothing, i tried debugging on netbeans. Clicking on the submenu's does not evoke the event as it's supposed to in the script.

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem but I do see something that might cause an error. In your `$.post` call, you're `data` argument may be mal-formatted.

Change: `username: <%= session.getAttribute("username") %>;`
To: `username: '<%= session.getAttribute("username") %>';` (wrapped in quotes)

Comment: @RicoKahler hi, i tried implementing your solution. Nothing changed. The click event still isn't being invoked.

But strangely if i change my id in the script from #dropdownmenu to #profile li, the event gets invoke. But it does not work for the submenu's  i tried using the #profile li id nothing happened as well.

Comment: did you try adding an event listner to the the `myitinerary` element directly i.e.: `$('#myitinerary').click(event => /* your code */)`

Comment: yes i just tried that. Nothing seems to be happening,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, i needed to modify a few things on my script. And it worked later.

```
$(function() {  
                $("#profile li").click(function(event) {
                    if(event.target.id === 'myitinerary')
                    {
                        $.post({
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {username: '<%= session.getAttribute("name") %>' },
                            url: "GetItineraries",
                            success: function(result){
                                $('#content2').empty();
                                $("#content3").empty();
                                $("#content4").empty();
                                $('#content').html(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```